# Script to transform content of a list in text file to a table in CSV file

Tags: csv, powershell

I have a text file which list servers info such as below:

```
server1  
Status: on  
CPU: 4 cores  
Memory: 256GB  
server2  
Status: off  
server3  
Status: on  
CPU: 8 cores  
Memory: 512GB
```

I want to transform it to CSV file such as below:

```
Name    Status  CPU Memory  
server1 on  4   256  
server2 off     
server3 on  8   512
```

I have search intensively in the net, but couldn't find any solution. Would really appreciate if someone can provide me some answers here.

Comment: Generally speaking it is a good idea to demonstrate what you have already tried.  That being said, I have posted an answer that should work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This distinguishes between lines without a colon (server names) and lines with a colon (server properties), and builds up a dataset for each server, resetting every time it gets to a new server name.

```
# For each line in the text file
Get-Content d:\data.txt | Foreach {

    if ($_ -notmatch ':') {                        # Line is a server name, reset.
        if ($server) { [pscustomobject]($server) } # Output dataset (skip 1 at beginning).
        $server = [ordered]@{'Name'=$_.Trim()}     # create new dataset.
    } else {                                       # Line is a server property
        $key, $value = $_.split(':')               # Process line.
        $server[$key.Trim()] = $value.Trim()       # Add details to dataset.
    }

} | Export-Csv D:\data.csv -NoTypeInformation      # Export, without PS Type details.
```

Edit: The above version only works if the file has a newline at the end. Here's a variant which runs if the file does not have a newline at the end, the same logic but this time with a `switch` toggle between lines with colons and lines without, and using the `ForEach -End {}` block to output the last entry.

```
Get-Content D:\data.txt | ForEach { Switch -Regex ($_) {
    ':' {$key, $value = $_.Split(':'); $block[$key] = $value; break}
    default {if ($block) {[pscustomobject]$block}; $block = [ordered]@{'Name'=$_ }}
}} -End {[pscustomobject]$block}
```

(Yeah, you could spread it out to 20 lines instead of 4... or add an `-End{}` block to the original).

Comment: Your solution missed the last server, the output only display 2 servers from my example... I tried it on my complete list that contains 97 servers, the output contains only 96 servers, the last server is missing...

Comment: @Edwin ahh, I had put a newline (blank line) at the end of the file, and that causes it to output the last server.

Comment: Can you fix that? I like your solution as it is short, simple & flexible as well, as i have tried your code with other similar files but with a lot more info, it works as well, but again with the last server missing in the output...

Answer (score 0):

This solution assumes each line is formatted consistently.  I.e., server names are always on a line by themselves and each of the other properties have a colon followed by a space between the property name and the property value.  This answer does not assume each server always has all three properties, CPU, memory, and status, as indicated by your sample data.

```
$data = @()
$intput = "D:\Working\data.txt"
$output = "D:\Working\data.csv"

# Loop over each line in the text file.
foreach ($_ in Get-Content $intput) {

    # Get the index of the ':' in the line.
    $index = $_.IndexOf(":")

    # If the index is -1 then the line is a server name.
    # Create a new object and add it to the array.
    if ($index -eq -1) {
        $data += New-Object -TypeName PsCustomObject -Property @{ Name = $_; Status = ""; CPU = ""; Memory = "" }
    }
    # If the index is not -1 then the line is a property.
    # Update the property of the last object added to the array.
    else {
        $propertyName = $_.Substring(0, $index)
        $propertyValue = $_.Substring($index + 2, $_.Length - $index - 2)

        switch ($propertyName) {
            "CPU"    { $data[$data.Length - 1].CPU    = $propertyValue }
            "Memory" { $data[$data.Length - 1].Memory = $propertyValue }
            "Status" { $data[$data.Length - 1].Status = $propertyValue }
        }
    }
}

# Export the data to a CSV file.
$data | Export-Csv $output -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Your assumption is correct, each line is indeed formatted consistently. Your solution works fine except for the columns are not in the order I need them to be, hence I've edited the last line as such: `$data | Select-Object -property Name, Status, CPU, Memory | Export-Csv $output -NoTypeInformation`... Thank you so so much :)